# How to extract information from given sentences

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am building a system that will receive queries related to file management as 
*deleting, copying, moving, creating new item ...*

So, what is the best approach to extract information from them like below :

```
can you delete file "file name" from "folder name"
```

then system should collect :

```
Action : deleting
upon   : "file name"
destination : "folder name"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natural language processing is rather complex, and there are many challenges that make parsing unstructured natural language queries like this more difficult than it might seem, depending on how broad the underlying set of commands is.

But in general, you would probably try to run the query through a [part-of-speech tagger](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html) to extract verb phrases for the actions, verb-object pairs for upon/destination, etc. Then you would map these terms to a list of acceptable synonyms for each action. For instance you might have a list of synonyms for "delete" such as `['delete', 'remove', 'rm', 'toss', 'eliminate', ...]`, etc and then set action to delete if the verb phrase contains any of these words. Regarding how to use the NLTK POS tagger and other tools to parse queries, take a look at this tutorial, which covers many of the difficulties in analyzing the semantics of sentences: [Analyzing the Meaning of Sentences](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html)

You might also want to check out these related threads:

- [How to process natural language queries?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-to-process-natural-language-queries)
- [Natural Language to SQL query](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31617/natural-language-to-sql-query?rq=1)

You had mentioned finding an academic paper on this, and if you are looking for more journal articles I suggest searching for the term "natural language query" (and variations thereof). A [search for this on Semantic Scholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org/search?year%5B0%5D=2010&year%5B1%5D=2020&q=natural%20language%20query&sort=relevance) from 2010-present turned up more than 75,000 results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply 
I have already tried that solution using *NLTK Chunking parser*, but the grammar I used didn't fulfill the required accuracy.
I have read some research papers like https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050914005304], it introduce a certain representation for the query called *KS-Representation* but I couldn't find any resource for it so far